# md5 is not working on complex data types in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, hash, md5

I am trying to calculate hash using md5 function in pyspark on entire row. In pyspark dataframe I have multiple complex data types present for few columns.

```
for e.g :  col: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)

 for e.g :  col: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
```

when I try to calculate md5 on entire row , md5 throws an error with below message:

```
**`col`' is of array<array<string>> type. argument 28 requires (array<string> or string) type, however, '`col`' is of array<array<string>> type**
```

code to calculate md5:

```
def prepare_data_md5(data):
    """ Prepare the data with md5 column.

    :param data: input DataFrame object
    :return: output DataFrame object
    """
    return data.withColumn("hash", md5(concat_ws(*data.columns)))
```

1.Is there some other function I could use for hash and that works for complex data types too ?
2. Is there some library available in pyspark or python for flattening complex data types , so that I could calculate md5 over flattened data-frame ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is some function available in that calculates hash for complex types.

If you have array and string columns then use **`concat_ws`** and **`array_concat`** to convert complex types to strings then apply **`md5`**.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---+------+
#| id|   arr|
#+---+------+
#|  a|[1, 2]|
#|  b|[3, 4]|
#+---+------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("tmp",concat_ws(",",col("arr"))).\
withColumn("new",md5(concat_ws(",",col("id"),array_join(col("arr"),",")))).\
drop("tmp").\
show(10,False)
#+---+------+--------------------------------+
#|id |arr   |new                             |
#+---+------+--------------------------------+
#|a  |[1, 2]|9f357697a277b1e5a8315035e7d95984|
#|b  |[3, 4]|578bec981ad992ddb641a45969babab1|
#+---+------+--------------------------------+

#dynamic way

df1=df.withColumn("arr",array_join(col("arr"),","))

df1.withColumn("md5",md5(concat_ws(",",*[col(x) for x in df1.columns]))).show(10,False)
#+---+---+--------------------------------+
#|id |arr|md5                             |
#+---+---+--------------------------------+
#|a  |1,2|9f357697a277b1e5a8315035e7d95984|
#|b  |3,4|578bec981ad992ddb641a45969babab1|
#+---+---+--------------------------------+
```